# How do I get camel casing using a PostgresDataSource in loopback?

Tags: loopbackjs

We have an app where someone have implemented a query using the datasource directly in loopback. I'm not the developer, but the use case is filtering on a column where you need to do a join to get the value to filter on. Because of this use case we have something that looks like this (typescript):

```
await this.dataSource.execute(`
    SELECT columnA, columnB, camelCaseColumn FROM tab1 a INNER JOIN tab2 c ON tab1.id = tab2.tab1Is AND columnFromTab2 = ${valueToFilterOn};`);
```

When running the query above the result will have `camelCaseColumn` in lower case like `camelcasecolumn`, where I need it to be in camel case.

Is there an option I can provide or something else I can do to get it in camel case. I'm pretty sure it is possible since it is the same datasource as the repositories use and they return it in a proper format.

Answer (score 2):

Check your `MODEL_NAME.json` file and change/add the `postgres.columnName` option to the property.

```
    "camelCaseColumn": {
      "type": "String",
      "postgresql": {
        "columnName": "camelCaseColumn"
      }
    },
```

EDIT: I forgot `lb4` doesn't declare model properties like that, put the settings inside your property decorator.

```
  @property({
    "postgresql": {
      "columnName": "camelCaseColumn"
    }
  })
```

[source](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/PostgreSQL-connector.html)

Also you are at risk of injection with that query.  Use a prepared statement.

```
await this.dataSource.execute(`
  SELECT 
  columnA, columnB, camelCaseColumn 
  FROM tab1 a 
    INNER JOIN tab2 c ON tab1.id = tab2.tab1Is AND columnFromTab2 = ?;`
  ,[valueToFilterOn]);
```

Comment: is this the same in loopback4?

Comment: (I'm quite new to loopback), but it doesn't seem like looback4 has the json models. I can't find any in a totally fresh project I created just to experiment before applying what I would like to do in the real project.

Comment: In my case it doesn't seem like the data source uses the model if I invoke the `execute` directly, but it does work through the repositories.

Comment: Woops, forgot about `lb4` syntax, I added the edit to make it work properly in lb4

Comment: I won't be able to test this since I figured out how to really do it using the belong to stuff. So now it is working as intended. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @TomasJansson could you elaborate on your solution.

Comment: @MarvinIrwin could you explain what a prepared statement is, or provide some sort of link, I also insert my fields directly in the query.

Comment: @MarvinIrwin Also could you explain, how to insert the parameters, do you just use question mark each time and put them in order?

Comment: @VikramKhemlani in this specific scenario I started with the docs here: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Relations.html and worked my way from there.